# Search for a item in CListCtrl

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

I am trying to find the index of a item in CListCtrl with specific data. In my case the data (not the item text) is the unique criterion by which I compare the items.

I tried to use [CListCtrl::FindItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class?view=vs-2019#finditem), but the function expects [LVFINDINFOW*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-lvfindinfow) - I don't think it works for me. I also tried to iterate the clistctrl - again unsuccessfully.

Thanks in advance to everyone who gets involved!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you looking to match the `lParam` data of items? Can you provide a snippet of the code that you're using?

Comment: I'm trying to change the item text fot a given item in In CListView::OnUpdate(). But the unique in the item is the data, which i setted up with (CListCtrl::SetItemData). So in OnUpdate I have:                                                                                                                                                                                                                               oListCtrl.SetItemText(?, CityColumnName, pNewCity->szName);                            So I want to replace the ? with index of the changed item in the ClListView.

Comment: @AdrianMole, I have did it, thanks to you. I didn't know that lParam is the Item Data, that is my unique specifier. Thanks! :)

Comment: Just for 'completeness', I have posted an answer to your question! This (hopefully) will make your post useful to future visitors to the site. (IMHO, it's a good question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the 'data' for an item in a `CListCtrl` using the [`SetItemData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class?view=vs-2019#setitemdata) member function, you are *actually* setting the `lParam` field of its associated `LVITEM` structure, as indicated in the documentation linked above:

> **Remarks**
>   This value is the lParam member of the LVITEM structure, as
>   described in the Windows SDK.

So, if you want to search for an item with the given data, set the `flags` member of the `LVFINDINFOW` structure to `LVFI_PARAM` , and its `lParam` field to the data value you're looking for; then call the [`FindItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class?view=vs-2019#finditem) function using that structure:

```cpp
LVFINDINFOW findInfo;
LPARAM searchData = 42; // Or whatever you're looking for
findInfo.flags = LVFI_PARAM;
findInfo.lParam = searchData;
int dataPos = myListCtrl.FindItem(-1, &findInfo);
//...
```